# Comparing convexity in multivariate functions with univariate ones

Tags: functions

Suppose I have a function of a single variable:
$$
y=f\left(x\right)
$$
where $f_{x}>0$ and $f_{xx}>0,$ or that it is a convex function.
Now suppose that I have a function of multiple variables:
$$
y=g\left(x,z\right)
$$
where we know that $g_{x},g_{z},g_{xx},g_{zz}>0$ , such that the
function is convex in both of its arguments. I can easily compare
the convexity between $f$ and$g$ in $x$ (compare $f_{xx}$and
$g_{xx}$), this does not seem correct, because of the presence of
$z$ in the $g$ function. Is there a way to compare the degree of
convexity in both functions? While in the first case, just looking
at $f_{xx}$ is all that you need to know about convexity, is there
a summary measure for the function $g$ to summarize the convexity
of both arguments in one measure?

Comment: The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix is typically used to study the convexity of a multivariable function like $g$. The part of your question about comparing the degree of convexity of $f$ and $g$ is unclear.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I see. Essentially, for example, if f(x)=x^2, then this function possesses a degree of convexity that is greater than say f(x)=x^1.5.  In the univariate case it is clear. However, when we have two inputs, is there  a measure of convexity that can be used to compare with the univariate case?